# Adding a list view item to a listview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I would have thought that I should be able to do something like this:

```
ListViewItem lvi = MyListView.Items.Add();
```

But `MyListView.Items.Add()` returns an integer.  This seems to differ from the way it’s done in WinForms, can anyone point me in the right direction as to how this is achieved?

WPF Listview:

```
    <ListView Margin="12,108,12,12" Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column1" Width="300" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column2" Width="100" />                    
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add an item to the list, right?

Try:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

MyListView.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Comment: I would also recommend to bind data to your list view and then instead of adding a ListViewItem add the class you bound to the ListView.

Comment: It could look like this:

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyClass}">
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" Header="Some header" />
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>

then in the code you can add an item of type MyClass.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go a bit further and checkout an online tutorial such as [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1) or [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFListView09092008224322PM/WPFListView.aspx). WPF controls often can't be treated in the same way as WinForm controls when it comes to handling data and binding...